# bring Jinternal frame infront of everything

Tags: java, jinternalframe

in this code when the new button is clicked, the Jinternalframe goes behind the button, even if i add anything else like, jlabel, jtextfield, etc, the internalframe opens behind everything. i tried the tofront() and movetofront() functions, but it doesnt seem to work. plz help, thanks.

code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Messages2 extends JFrame {

    JFrame frame;
    JButton button1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Messages2 window = new Messages2();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Messages2() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 220, 220);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton btnNew = new JButton("New Message");
        btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
                JInternalFrame intFrame = new JInternalFrame(
                        "JInternalFrame demo");

                intFrame.setMaximizable(true);
                intFrame.setIconifiable(true);
                intFrame.setResizable(true);
                intFrame.setClosable(true);
                intFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                intFrame.setSize(320, 240);
                // intFrame.pack();
                intFrame.setVisible(true);

                desktopPane.add(intFrame);

                frame.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }

        });
        btnNew.setBounds(1, 35, 145, 31);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNew);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when the new button is clicked, the Jinternalframe goes behind the button, even if i add anything else like, jlabel, jtextfield, etc,

Based on the code you posted in you last question (before you deleted it), you are attempting to add all your components directly to the frame. Swing paints components in the reverse order that a component is added. So since the internal frame is added last it is painted first and then all the other components are painted over top of it.

This is not the way you should be working with a JInternalFrame. You need to separate the JDesktopPane/JInternalFrames from your other components and work with each separately.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for basic information and examples.

1. the internal frame is added to a JDesktopPane which is added to the frame.
2. Don't use a null layout for your other components. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. These components should be added to a panel and then the panel added to the frame.

The panel and the desktop pane must be added to different areas of the frame. For example:

```
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I edited my code above, it still doesnt seem to work, what am i still missing? if i keep different layouts, the internalframe still goes behind the button..

Comment: I specifically stated the panel (button) and desktop pane must go to different areas of the frame and gave example code. Does your code look like mine? What part of the BorderLayout are you adding the button to?  If you don't specify a position where do you think the button will go? Why don't you start with a working example? I gave you a link to the tutorial. While you are reading the tutorial you can always read the section on layout managers which also has a section on `How to Use BorderLayout` which contains working examples.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using JInternalFrame correctly. It should only be placed within a JDesktopPane, something you're not doing and that I suggest that you start doing. Please check the [appropriate tutorial on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

Your button and your JInternalFrame now fill the field since you're using the JFrame's default BorderLayout. Suggestion:

- First and foremost, explain **fully** just what **exact** effect/user experience you're trying to achieve. Are you sure that a JInternalFrame is your best choice here?
- Learn about and use the layout managers to their best advantage.
- If you're going to use a JInternalFrame, then while it's OK to add the JInternalFrame in your ActionListener, you're usually going to want to add the JDesktopPane to the GUI on GUI creation, not in the ActionListener.

Comment: I edited my code above, it still doesnt seem to work, what am i still missing? if i keep different layouts, the internalframe still goes behind the button..